# Conditional compilation confusion and failure

Tags: c++, c, makefile, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I want to compile different files with a common *.c file. Like I want to compile `A.c common.c` xor `B.c common.c` but I can't figure out how to achieve that.

Can you please tell me how do I make common.c use different headers without using my text editor to change the headers list every time I want to compile

So let's say I have 3 files: A.c, B.c and common.c.

A.h and B.h define an enum `enum {Mon, Tues, Wed...}` in different ways. And that enum is used in common.c. So I can't just do in common.c:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
```

What I thought of doing is to use preprocessor directives:

In common.h

```
#define A 1
#define B 2
```

In A.c

```
#define COMPILE_HEADER A
```

And in common.c

```
#if COMPILE_HEADER == A 
#include A.h 
#end
```

This doesn't work, of course, because the compiler didn't visit the A.c file to find `#define COMPILE_HEADER A`

So can you please tell me how do I make common.c use different headers without using my text editor to change the headers list every time I want to compile?

Comment: Use a single header common.h and link with either A.o or B.o in your Makefile/IDE/command line ?

Comment: If only the implementation of the function is different, why do you need two separate header files? The implementations are in the .c files, the header files should only have declarations (unless the functions are inline).

Comment: Many compilers let you specify preprocessor flags on the command line, so you can use a `#ifdef` construct and control it with the parameters passed to the compiler.

Comment: You should think hard about what you really want to achieve. If `A` and `B` implement `f()` in different ways, then their headers should be compatible and ideally there should only be one `AB.h` header. If you need separate `A.h` and `B.h` headers, then there is probably something wrong.

Comment: acutally, its not a funciton. maybe I should have said this from the start. It's an enum. Like enum {Mon, Tues, Wed...}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty complicated to explain, but I'll give it a try.

### Explaination

The compiler, for example gcc, gets the input files provided, includes (literally just copy-pastes) the header files into their respective places (where the `#include` directive is located) in the `*.c` file, then compiles the file to the object (`*.o`) file. No executable is created. Here comes the linker, which is included in gcc. It takes the `*.o` files and links them into one executable.

The problem is, that the files are compiled independently, and then linked together. I mean, that predefinition like `int func(int param);` is like saying to compiler "Hey man, don't worry about any usage of `func` in the code, the linker will care". Compiler then just saves this usage as external symbol in the corresponding `*.o` file, and when linker is doing his job, he firstly finds the location of the symbol definition (the function implementation) and then just points to it whenever the func is called.

Try to include function definition in header file, then include it in 2 or more files from same project (compiled/linked together). Compiler will say it's ok, since the code is correct and the generated code is valid. Then, the linker will try to link it into one executable and he would have to decide which version of the same name-param function should it link to. Since most developer tools are not really good at making the right choices, he will just yell at you saying "hey man, you gave me two definitions of same function, what to do now?". This results with an error like this:

```
obj\Release\b.o:b.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of 'func(int)'
obj\Release\a.o:a.cpp:(.text+0xc): first defined here
```

What about having two `main` in one project?

```
obj\Release\b.o:b.cpp:(.text.startup+0x0): multiple definition of 'main'
obj\Release\a.o:a.cpp:(.text.startup+0x0): first defined here
```

Both files compile, but they cannot be linked together.

The header files are meant to contain class definitions and function predefinitions to allow you to write them only once, and then share between all files that want to use them. You can always just type class definitions for each file separately (as long as they stay same) and use them just like you would use them in .h file, same applies for function predefinitions.

There comes your problem. You have to compile only one file, not include only one. You can do this by using the preprocessor trick, but I wouldn't reccomend as solution, since it can be solved much easier (I'll tell you how in a moment).

### TL;DR; (The actual answer without explaination)

You can #ifdef / #ifndef both files, then in another `*.c` define (or not define) some value. For example:

**A.cpp**

```
#include "t.h"

#ifdef USE_A
int func(int a)
{
    return a + 5;
}
#endif
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include "t.h"

#ifndef USE_A
int func(int a)
{
    return a * 10;
}
#endif
```

**T.h**

```
#ifndef T_H
#define T_H

//Or comment to use B
#define USE_A

int func(int a);

#endif // T_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "t.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << func(3);
}
```

Notice that the `#ifdef`/`#ifndef` are **after** the `#include`, so the preprocessor knows which one to compile. Also, it's not possible (at least I can't think of any way) to make the definition in any .c file, because they are compiled separately (as described above). You could use the -D switch, but that involves messing with build configurations in environments and if you want to do that it's better to try the second solution presented bellow.

### Better answer

You should choose one file to compile with each version. It hardly depends on your needs, but basically instead of using `g++ main.cpp a.cpp b.cpp` you should compile either a.cpp or b.cpp. If you are using integrated environment like Visual Studio or Code Blocks, the configuration managers allow you to decide which file to include. I mean, those Debug/Release dropdowns can contain your own entries, which will customize your project. Then, switching between the A.cpp and B.cpp is just a question of choosing appropiate option in the always-visible bar in your environment.

If you want a more detailed tutorial on how to manage configurations on Code::Blocks or Visual Studio create appropiate question on stackoverflow and it will be answered in no time :)

Comment: thanks a lot. 
I think that I;ll need to change the T.h file when I;ll want to compile B.c.
What i prefere to do is to somehow organize this to compile the right header automatically. Like gcc A.cpp common.cpp will use A.h and gcc B.cpp common.c will use B.h.

Comment: also I need to say that it's an enum not a function that I need to define in A.h and B.h. Like `enum {MON, TUES...}` in A.h and `enum {SUN, MON...}` in B.h. I need this enum in common.c and A.h/B.h when I compile `gcc A.c common.c` XOR `gcc B.c common.c`

Comment: @JeniaIvanov You can then just #ifdef/#else the enum itself, while keeping it defined in one file :)